# Error al crear un plugin personalizado Vuejs + Typescript

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Tengo esta estructura de mi plugin index y service:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

service.ts:

```
declare interface Params {
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  type?: string;
  duration?: number;
}

export default class ServiceToast {
  public toastRef: any; // component

  public constructor(modalRef: any) {
    this.toastRef = modalRef;
    console.log(this.toastRef);
  }

  public open(params: Params) {
    this.toastRef.open(params);
  }
}
```

Básicamente he creado un servicio que recibe el componente para que este interacture a gusto con el componente.

index.ts:

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Toast from '@/components/_includes/layouts/Toast.vue';
import ServiceToast from './service';

const ToastPlugin = {
  install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
    Vue.mixin({
      created() {
        Vue.prototype.$toast = new ServiceToast(Toast);
      },
    });
  },
};

export default ToastPlugin;
```

Donde instalo el plugin y utilizo el service que mostre anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí llamo al plugin y le hago el Vue.use correspondinete pero cuando lo quiero llamar en cualquier componente:

```
<a @click="$toast.open({ title: 'Hola mundo' })">Hola, dame click!</a>
```

Me sale el siguiente error:
"TypeError: this.toastRef.open is not a function"

En el shims-vue-plugin.d.ts:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import Vue from 'vue';
import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import 'webpack-env';
import { FieldFlagsBag } from 'vee-validate';
import { SnackbarProgrammatic as Snackbar, DialogProgrammatic as Dialog } from 'buefy';
import ServiceToast from './app-config/toast/service';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $auth: any;
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
    veeFields: FieldFlagsBag;
    $dialog: typeof Dialog;
    $snackbar: typeof Snackbar;
    $toast: ServiceToast;
  }
}


declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Process extends __WebpackModuleApi.NodeProcess {
    server: boolean;
  }
}
```

Sabe alguien que podría ser? o que me esta faltando ya que no llego encontrar el error.

UPDATE:
Este es el componente Modal:

```
<template>
  <ModalComponent v-model="isActive" :close-inside="false" :is-footer="false"
                  ref="toast" @close="$emit('close')" :width="240" :min-width="240" class="toast">
    <template slot="body">
      <div class="toast-content has-text-centered">
        <figure class="image is-128x128 flex-center" v-if="type === 'success'">
          <img src="/static/img/images/success.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="image is-128x128 flex-center" v-if="type === 'warning'">
          <img src="/static/img/images/warning.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="image is-128x128 flex-center" v-if="type === 'danger'">
          <img src="/static/img/images/danger.png">
        </figure>
        <h1 class="is-size-3 has-text-weight-bold has-text-danger">{{ title }}</h1>
        <p v-if="description">{{ description }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </ModalComponent>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  Component, Prop, Vue, Watch,
} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import ModalComponent from '@/components/_includes/ModalComponent.vue';

@Component({ components: { ModalComponent } })
export default class Toast extends Vue {
  public isActive: boolean = false;

  public title: string = '';

  public description?: string = '';

  public type?: string = 'success';

  public duration?: number = 1000;

  open(params: any) {
    this.isActive = true;
    this.title = params.title;
    this.description = params.description;
    this.type = params.type ? params.type : this.type;
    this.duration = params.duration ? params.duration : this.duration;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.close();
    }, this.duration);
  }

  close() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Tu componente Toast tiene un metodo open()? creo que es necesario incluirlo en la pregunta

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Si tiene, ahora actualizo la pregunta. Gracias por preguntar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno la solución simplemente era instanciar el componente como clase y hacerle un mounted para que este en cualquier parte del proyecto:

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Toast from '../../components/_includes/layouts/Toast.vue';
import ServiceToast from './service';

export default {
  install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
    const toastComponent = new Toast();
    Vue.mixin({
      created() {
        Vue.prototype.$toast = new ServiceToast(toastComponent);
      },
      mounted() {
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.append(el);
        toastComponent.$mount(el);
      },
    });
  },
};
```

Espero le sirva a alguien si quiere hacer algo parecido :)

Comment: Creo que es mas eficiente tener un componente global en el arbol de la app y que tu plugin exponga un objeto con los datos y una variable bool que indique si debe mostrarse o no el Toast, me alegra que hayas encontrado una solución